# What's the R function for counting row wise unique pairs?

Tags: r, count, bigdata, frequency

I made two columns which show pairs of prescribed meds. Some of these pairs repeat, and I need to find the frequency/count of the unique pairs.
Can anyone help me?

- its a big data, I am just posting this photo to show my variables.

Comment: Don‘t post photos! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

If your data is `df`, and your medication columns are `med1` and `med2`, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, med1,med2)
```

but if it really is a large dataset, you might benefit from using `data.table` instead:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.N, .(med1,med2)]
```